# Sed command not working when trying to add object in Json

Tags: java, bash, sed

I'm trying to write a generic Java function that executes a Sed command on remote that adds a new object/line/value to Json in between 2 given parameters: opening section and end section.
I've come with the following Sed command but to no avail.

```
sed -E 's/]}/"my object to add"/'  jsonfile.json
```

] - states the opening section
} - states the ending section
The opening section and ending section may varies and can include several things together,
like: [], or specific object.
I can't use jk command.

Comment: sed really is not the appropriate tool to be using to edit Json. Use a proper library

Comment: The command line you show has an unmatched single quote.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it. I ran it with the closing single quote. Just a typo here, so problem still ensues